# Make filters with an object for images jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many image tags within a div with a class of `google-image-layout`and all the images have data attributes such as

```
data-anger="0" data-disgust="0" data-facedetected="0" data-fear="0" data-happiness="0" data-largefacedetected="0" data-neutral="0" data-sadness="0" data-surprise="0"
```

I want an advice that how can I make a filter with such data attributes. Basically, I have an object with every image called `Tags` and that tags have values of

```
FaceDetected : 0
Anger : 0
Disgust : 0
LargeFaceDetected : 1
Neutral : 0
Sadness : 1
```

This is the values in Tags object. What I thought about filtering is to add these values to as data-attributes and then do the filtering. But I need advice how could I make a filter from these values for images?

```
  tags = ""
  $.each Images, (i, Image) ->
    tangRef = storageRef.child(capitalizeFirstLetter("#{Image.Path}"));
    tangRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) ->
      $.each Image.Tags, (i, value) ->

        tags += "data-#{i}='#{value}' "
        console.log "#{i} : #{value}"
      console.log tags
      image_tag = "<img #{tags} data-width='480' data-height='256' src='#{url}' />"
      $(".google-image-layout").append(image_tag)
      GoogleImageLayout.init()
      tags = ""
    ).catch (error) ->
      console.log error
      return
```

The above is the code which through I am adding the data attributes, is there any other way you can think about? to make it work? more sensibly?

Comment: But the img tag hasn't `Large Face` data attribute.

Comment: please create jsfiddle for your code to understand what you have actually tried?

Comment: You can try something like this: `$('[data-largefacedetected="1"]').show(); $('[data-largefacedetected="0"]').hide();`

Comment: Okay let me edit my question

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mapping between search terms and the data attributes that are related to it. I.e.

```
function SearchMap(term, attr){
    this.term = term;
    this.attr = attr;
}

var arry = [];
arry.push(new SearchMap('Large Face', 'largefacedetected'));
arry.push(new SearchMap('Fear', 'fear'));
arry.push(new SearchMap('Anger', 'anger'));
arry.push(new SearchMap('Happy', 'happiness'));
arry.push(new SearchMap('Disgust', 'disgust'));
```

Then when searching you can just find the data attribute related to the search term like so:

```
$("#search-btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".pic").hide();
  $("#console").empty();

    var val = $("#search-input").val();
    var result = $.grep(arry, function(e){ return e.term == val; });
    $("#console").append(JSON.stringify(result));

  //TODO: Check result length to see if any exists/Multiple 
  if(result.length == 1) {
    var attr = result[0].attr;
    $("div[data-"+attr+"='1']").show();
  }

});
```

Here is an example in jsFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/4shu6xy8/

Comment: @ijunaidfarooq In a basic sense yes, its only an example. There is no validation, as Its outside the scope of the question.